Deleting White Background on xml shape
I have a problem where in the following xml code there are several white areas left because I created a radius of 50 dp. And I want the white area to disappear, how do I do that?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/turkish_rose" />
    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="@color/red"
        />
</shape>

I've tried to reduce the radius but that's not what I mean, what I mean is how to remove the white area

The white area is the background.  Try making it transparent so it is not white.
